# How to estimate the value of a random variable in this multivariate setting

Tags: regression, missing-data

Forgive me for the crummy title.  Not sure how to describe what I want without giving an explicit example...

Suppose you go to various geographic regions and measure the population of some species.  Your resulting data looks something like this:

```
train <- data.frame(
  Region=c(1,2,3,4,5),
  BlackBears=c(NA, 45, 109, 63, 20),
  Deer=c(213, NA, 97, 80, NA),
  Alligators=c(41, 57, NA, 22, NA),
  Pelicans=c(116, 183, NA, 0, 52)
)

  Region BlackBears Deer Alligators Pelicans
1      1         NA  213         41      116
2      2         45   NA         57      183
3      3        109   97         NA       NA
4      4         63   80         22        0
5      5         20   NA         NA       52
```

What statistical model can you use to estimate the population of, say, Alligators in region 3?